# Was homosexuality illegal during the early Muslim rule of the Indian subcontinent?

Tags: india, sexuality, law, lgbt

Was homosexuality punished under the early Muslim rule in India, beginning with the Umayyad conquest of Punjab and Sinh in 712? The early Muslims were Arabs and part of a universal caliphate. After the caliphate collapsed, they were replaced in India by the Persian Samanid Empire, and the Persianised Ghaznavid dynasty.

Thus, unlike the Delhi Sultanate and Mughal Empire in the 13th and 16th centuries, which were largely confined to India and became progressively more native, the earlier Islamic regimes were wholly foreign and based outside of India.

Comment: This question is not only not a duplicate of the one it is marked to be a duplicate of, it also states how it is different from that question. I am voting to reopen.